Define a new process $X(t)=3N_1(t)+5N_2(t)$, $X(0)=0$ What is the probability that there exists some $0≤t<T$ such that $X(t)=3$?
Suppose $N_1(t)$ and $N_2(t)$ are independent Poisson processes with rates $h_1$ and $h_2$, respectively. Define a new process
$$
X(t)=3N_1(t)+5N_2(t)\ ,\  X(0)=0\ .
$$
What is the probability that there exists some $0\le t< T$ such that $X(t)=3$?
I noticed $X(t)=3$ only when $N_1(t)=1$ and $N_2(t)=0$.
I started with
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(N_1(T)=1\text{ and } N_2(T)=0)\ &=\ P(N_1(T)=1)\cdot P(N_2(T)=0)
\\
&=\ h_1te^{-h_1t}\cdot e^{-h_2t}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
But I don't know how to continue with this problem.
Why is $X(0)=0$ given and is it of any use here?
What should be the correct answer?

I edited the post from the mathjax point of view, hoping that it is more readable now. The "maths" inside was left as it was. In the last displayed relation there is no $t$ at the start. Please correct...

Poisson processes have to "start" at some finite time; else if $N(t)$ is the number of arrivals during $(-\infty, t],$ or during $(-\infty, t)$, the value of $N(t)$ is unbounded. Very often, Poisson processes are defined for $t>0$ only, with $N(t)$ denoting the number of arrivals/occurrences in the interval $(0,t]$ as opposed to $[0,t)$ the way your question is. If the process is defined for $t\geq 0$, with $[0,T)$ being the interval, the value of $N(0)$ or $X(0)$ becomes very relevant.

As Poisson random variables are non-negative, the condition $X(0)=0$ implies that
at $t=0$ we must have $N_1(0)=N_2(0)=0$.
As you observed, the event $X(t)=3$ for some in $[0,T]$ can occur only if the first
event from the Poisson process $N_1(t)$ occurs before the first event from
$N_2(t)$, for else $X(t)$ would directly increment to $5$.
Furthermore, the first event from $N_1(t)$ also has to occur in $[0,T]$.
Denote as ${\bf T}_1$ and ${\bf T}_2$ the time of the first event in
$N_1(t)$ and $N_2(t)$, respectively.
Conditioning on the value of ${\bf T}_1=t$ we have
\begin{eqnarray*} 
P({\bf T}_1 < {\bf T}_2, {\bf T}_1 < T) & = & 
\int_0^{\infty} \, P({\bf T}_1 < {\bf T}_2, {\bf T}_1 < T| {\bf T}_1 = t) \, h_1 e^{-h_1 t} \, dt \\ 
& = & \int_0^T \, P(t < {\bf T}_2) \, h_1 e^{-h_1 t} \, dt \\ 
& = & \int_0^T \,  e^{-h_2 t} \, h_1 e^{-h_1 t} \, dt \\ 
& = &  \frac{h_1}{h_1+h_2} \, \left[ 1 - e^{-(h_1+h_2) T} \right] 
\end{eqnarray*}
